# How to change a Button's background for a certain amount of time and then it change back on an Android app

Tags: android

I am typing a program where I need to change the background of a button for a certain amount of time, say 1 second and then it change back to the original state. I know how to set a background, I just don't know how to get it to update the UI. I am pretty sure I need to use a Handler, but even after doing research I am hazy on how they should be implemented. Please enlighten me.

Comment: what would trigger this change in background color? One possible way is to use an AsyncTask - change the color of the button in onPreExecute(), use Thread.sleep(1000) in doInBackground() and then revert to the original color in onPostExecute()

Comment: I change the button background with a .setBackgroundResource. I originally changed the background then called a thread that slept for 1500 and then changed it back. The only problem is the screen would never show the change.

Comment: You should never invoke Thread.sleep() on the UI thread. You could use an AsyncTask, like I suggested or take a look at this answer, that uses a Handler. The code is clean and compact: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655977/android-updating-ui-with-a-button

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you are having any trouble.

Comment: can you post your code so that we can made necessary change

Comment: I actually got it working with a handler.postDelayed(new Runable()....Thanks for all your quick and insightful help.

Answer (score 0):

i Think this is simple and will work

```
 private void startthread() {
anihandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        updatestatusalternate();
    }

};
aniThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    sleep(1000);
                    anihandler.sendMessage(anihandler
                            .obtainMessage());


    }
};
aniThread.start();
}

   private void updatestatusalternate() {
    if(updatestatusflag)
    {
        //chnge your background resource here
        updatestatusflag=false;
    }
    else
    {
                   //chnge your background resource here
        updatestatusflag=true;
    }

}
```